# Splitting a map value

Tags: javascript, jquery, dictionary

I have a map that has data of this type:

```
{4e237b32eca4a6103061abf7:"27.94904038727,-82.6213887207031,test again,"}
```

I am trying to split the value with the below code but it states that split is not a valid command.  I suspect it is not seeing it as a string.

```
          $.each(arrayRemove, function (key, value) {
                var data = value.split(",");
                var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data[i + 0], data[i + 1]);
                ...
```

Can I cast it or how should this be done?

Comment: Is it `[{...}]` that's the map?

Comment: If I run `"27.94904038727,-82.6213887207031,test again,".split(",")` in Firebug I get an array as expected. So your data is probably not as it seems to be and you presented here.

Comment: What is the js error that you get?

Comment: value,split(",")   ReferenceError: split is not defined

Comment: I did as you did and it works but in the above clip the value is looks like the map entry - which contains the key and value

Comment: @Jeff: in your last comment you used a comma after `value` which is of course invalid. Use a **dot**. But that's probably a typo... Or...

Comment: provide the value of `arrayRemove` before you pump it into `.each`

Comment: Properties cannot start with a number (though [you can hack around that by explicitly providing string quotes around the key, and then your code works](http://jsfiddle.net/BVfmT/)). Make a testcase that demonstrates your problem.

Comment: @Jeff: By testcase Tomalak was refering to a [JSFiddle.net](http://www.jsfiddle.net) example...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case `value` is `{4e237b32eca4a6103061abf7:"27.94904038727,-82.6213887207031,test again,"}` which is an object without a method split. So you might need to go deeper:

```
$.each(arrayRemove, function (key, value) {
     $.each(value, function (key, str) {
            var data = str.split(",");
            var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(str[i + 0], str[i + 1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

That's invalid JSON.

Try this:

```
var my_map = {"key_4e237b32eca4a6103061abf7":"27.94904038727,-82.6213887207031,test again,"}

console.log(my_map.key_4e237b32eca4a6103061abf7.split(','));
```

Comment: Who said he's parsing JSON? But otherwise you're right yes. Identifier starting with a number is invalid anyway (*The first character must be a letter, an underscore (_), or a dollar sign ($)*)

Comment: Yep I'd add a prefix like `{"key_4e237b32eca4a6103061abf7":"foobar"}`

Answer (score 0):

### Answer not yet possible

Information and data you've provided can't be used to provide a satisfactory answer. but in the meantime I can answer your minor question about casting values to strings.

Casting whatever value to string is simply done by:

```
var casted = myVar + "";
```

Variable `casted` will hold a string even though `myVar` was any other type.

### Best assistance that can be given at the moment

I suggest you head over to [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) and put your code in that replicates the problem you're having. And we'll be able to fiddle with your test case and actually see what's the problem. **And of course provide a solution.**

Comment: @AlienWebguy: Or (arguably) simply `myVar.toString()`. All these are arguably simpler. One may prefer one over the other. Total personal preference of simplicity.